# ImportError: cannot import name '_UnstableArchMixin' from 'sklearn.base'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My environment is anaconda3(python 3.7).

I use this code to test `sklearn.cluster`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
plt.figure()
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, centers=[[-1,-1], [0,0], [1,1], [2,2]], cluster_std=[0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], random_state =9) #生成测试数据
for index,k in enumerate((2,3,4,5)):
    plt.subplot(2,2,index+1)
    y_pred = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=9).fit_predict(X)
    score=metrics.calinski_harabaz_score(X, y_pred)
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y_pred,s=10,edgecolor='k')
    plt.text(.99, .01, ('k=%d, score: %.2f' % (k,score)),transform=plt.gca().transAxes, size=10,horizontalalignment='right')
plt.show()
```

But when I run this code in pycharm,the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/test/test1.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
  File "E:\Anaconda37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
  File "E:\Anaconda37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\spectral.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..manifold import spectral_embedding
  File "E:\Anaconda37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .locally_linear import locally_linear_embedding, LocallyLinearEmbedding
  File "E:\Anaconda37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\locally_linear.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, _UnstableArchMixin
ImportError: cannot import name '_UnstableArchMixin' from 'sklearn.base' (E:\Anaconda37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a version thing, because I can see that class in the current sklearn.base source code.  Maybe try `pip install sklearn -U`

Comment: @Steve As you said,I tried `pip install sklearn -U`,but the error is still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified this file `E:\Anaconda37\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\locally_linear.py`

```
from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin, _UnstableArchMixi
```

change to:

```
from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
```

And

```
class LocallyLinearEmbedding(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin,_UnstableArchMixin):
```

change to

```
class LocallyLinearEmbedding(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
```

Then the error disappeared.And I checked this file in python3.6,there is no `_UnstableArchMixin` in the file.