# What would prevent scikit-learn, and more specifically sklearn.base, from importing into Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I cannot import any part of scikit-learn library package in Python. I need sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression but have tried importing various scikit-learn packages each without success. Has anyone had a similar issues with BaseEstimator, or see a solution to loading scikit-learn? Thanks for the help!

System Parameters

- Windows 10
- Anaconda 1.9.7
- scikit-learn 0.21.3

Tried:

- Uninstalling and resintalling scikit-learn with conda
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda distribution
- loading the specific item that seems to be issue with `from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator`
- running library in Jupyter Notebook, Microsoft VS Code, and Spyder

Code Entered: `from sklearn import linear_model`

Error Message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b94db01ee140> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn import linear_model

C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     74 else:
     75     from . import __check_build
---> 76     from .base import clone
     77     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     78 

C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     14 
     15 from . import __version__
---> 16 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     17 
     18 _DEFAULT_TAGS = {

C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     18 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     19 from .deprecation import deprecated
---> 20 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     21                          assert_all_finite,
     22                          check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>
     19 from numpy.core.numeric import ComplexWarning
     20 
---> 21 from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan
     22 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     23 from ..exceptions import NonBLASDotWarning

C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
     16 import scipy.sparse as sp
     17 import scipy
---> 18 from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
     19 
     20 

C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    114 from .dsolve import *
    115 from .interface import *
--> 116 from .eigen import *
    117 from .matfuncs import *
    118 from ._onenormest import *

C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
      9 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     10 
---> 11 from .arpack import *
     12 from .lobpcg import *
     13 

C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator

ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseEstimator' from 'sklearn.base' (C:\Util\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py)
```

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549270/importerror-cannot-import-name-multioutputmixin-from-sklearn-base/56592239)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'MultiOutputMixin' from 'sklearn.base'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549270/importerror-cannot-import-name-multioutputmixin-from-sklearn-base)